# How do I calculate the required size for a CheckedListBox?

Tags: winforms

I have written some code to automatically scale a CheckedListBox to its contents using mListBox.ItemHeight and mListBox.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(...).
The output from the string measurements is a bit dubious but what really puzzles me is how much to add for borders and such.

I tried both SystemInformation.Border3DSize (= 2) as well as the difference between ClientSize and Size (= 4).
But taking mListBox.ItemHeight * mListBox.Items.Count + 4 for the height makes it one pixel too small and a scrollbar appears.

For the width it does not work at all because it does not take the size of the checkboxes into account for which I can't seem to find a source.

How should I determine the size of the control?

Comment: It would help if you included sample images (before and after size fix). Also tag the language you are using. Another thing is it's not clear to me why would you need such behavior (if I understood you correctly).

Comment: I can show images and sample code later, since it takes a little time. I need it because I am overlaying the CheckedListBox over a grid for value selection and I need it to take on a useful size.

Comment: @Sarien: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: No, my solution looks similar to your answer. I was looking for a way to avoid the magic numbers like 20 px for the checkbox (I use 18 :) ).

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, it is typically easier to set the ClientSize rather than the whole Size. One thing to note about ItemHeight is that it does not include the margins of the item. Using a CheckedListBox with default settings, I had an ItemHeight of 13. But the ItemRectangle property had a height of 15.

So here is what I did. I added 9 items to the CheckedListBox (the first Item was longer than the rest), keeping the default size of the control as set by the designer. Then in the constructor of the form, I set the ClientSize like so:

```
this.checkedListBox1.ClientSize = new Size(TextRenderer.MeasureText(checkedListBox1.Items[0].ToString(), checkedListBox1.Font).Width + 20, checkedListBox1.GetItemRectangle(0).Height * checkedListBox1.Items.Count);
```

Notice I used TextRenderer.MeasureText to measure the text. It will typically give you better values than Graphics.MeasureString. By default, TextRenderer included a bit of padding in it's measurement. I also included a 20 pixel padding to account for the checkbox. Anyway, with TextRenderer.MeasureText, and the 20 pixel padding for width, and ItemRectangle * Items.Count for the height, that gave me a CheckedListBox that was sized to its contents without ScrollBars.

EDIT: If item widths vary, it may complicate setting the width, as you'll want to set the width based on the longest item. In this case you'll need to measure each item and keep track of which one was the longest.

EDIT 2: Ok so I dug around in the CheckedListBox source code. They use a default size of 13 plus a 3 pixel padding for the width and height of the checkbox. *But*, if VisualStyles is enabled, they call `CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize` to get the size to use because it takes into account the DPI settings. Most machines are set at 96 DPI so that method will still return a size of (13,13). So when you're measuring the text of the item, you can also pass the Graphics object and a CheckBoxState enum to the `CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize` to get a size. I used `System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal` for the state, but I'm not sure that the state matters. I tried `CheckBoxState.MixedDisabled` as well and it returned the same size, (13,13).

So to summarize, you can use `CheckBoxRenderer` to get the size of the checkbox, but you will still probably need to use some padding. This reduces the need for hardcoding a magic number to account for the checkbox. Since the checkbox is drawn and isn't an actual control, its size can't be determined like sizes of controls can.

Here is a link to the source of CheckedListBox. It wouldn't hurt to look at it. Specifically, look at the `protected override void OnDrawItem` method.

[CheckedListBox Source](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Net/Net/3@5@50727@3053/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/whidbey/netfxsp/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/CheckedListBox@cs/2/CheckedListBox@cs)